# ContentPresenter DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate, contentpresenter

I have a `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myTemplate">
    ...
</DataTemplate>
```

I want to use it as the `ContentTemplate` of a `ContentPresenter`:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding X}">
    <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate >
        <!-- ????? what goes here ????-->
    </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
</ContentPresenter>
```

How can I use the predefined `DataTemplate` in my `ContentPresenter`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You just need to reference the defined resource:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding X}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource myTemplate}"/>
```

Answer (score 8):

Should be something like:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding X}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource myTemplate}"/>
```

Although I wouldn't define a Template on a contentpresenter, I will select the correct template based on the type anyway.

Comment: i cant upvote your answer for some reason... it says i already voted

Comment: Two reasons for having templates on content presenter: 1. Provide separate view and edit template for the same object. 2. Split the view into two parts, e.g in a treeviewitem template you can show one part before the `ItemsPresenter` and one part after.